# nginx rewrite after location match

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx and just trying to do something which I believe should be simple. If I do:-

curl http://localhost:8008/12345678

I would expect the index.html page to be returned. But instead I get 404 not found. /usr/share/nginx/html/12345678 no such file

If I do curl http://localhost:8008/ I expect the request to be routed to http://someotherplace/ but instead I get 302 found and thats it.

Apologies for the basic questions but would be grateful for some advice!

This is the code:

```
server {
    listen 8008;
    server_name default_server;

    location / {
       rewrite ^/$ http://someotherplace/ redirect;
    }

    location ~ "^/[\d]{8}" {
       rewrite ^/$ /index.html;
       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the second part of your question, what do you mean by "routed"? The [302 found status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) is the correct response for a `rewrite...redirect` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^/$` does not match the URI `/12345678` - it only matches the URI `/`.

You could use:

```
rewrite ^ /index.html break;
```

The `^` is just one of many regular expressions that match anything. The `break` suffix causes the rewritten URI to be processed within the same `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

---

You can achieve the same result using the `try_files` directive:

```
location ~ "^/[\d]{8}" {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
```

The `=404` clause is never reached as `index.html` always exists - but `try_files` must have at least two parameters. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Thank you for that! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
server {
    listen 8008;
    server_name default_server;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://someotherplace/;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location ~ "^/[\d]{8}" {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break; 
    }
}
```

The `proxy_pass` will route the request to your remote destination and return the response.
Instead of `rewrite` you can use `try_files` as described by Richard Smith.